# Sequelize constraint on delete

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I would like to add a constraint inside my migration file, for example when I try and delete a row and there's another row inside another table that's referencing the row i'm deleting it needs to throw an error. There will also be multiple tables that will associate with the table.

```
return queryInterface.createTable('status', {
  id: {
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    unique: true
  },
  slug: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    unique: true
  },
  createdAt: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.DATE
  },
  updatedAt: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.DATE
  },
});
```

table status:
...
id

table locales:
...
id_status

table users
...
id_status

Comment: Add a constraint using foreign keys.

Comment: @tadman any examples? I see there's hasMany, belongs to relations do I need to use those or something else?

Comment: Worth a quick trip to [the documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/associations.html).

Comment: does it apply apply to migrations too?

Answer (score 2):

```
 id_status: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: 'status',
      key: 'id',
    },
onDelete: 'restrict'    
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  id_status: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: 'status',
      key: 'id',
      onDelete: 'restrict'    
    }
  },
```